# How to fetch last parameter of url using javascript?

Tags: javascript

my URL is https://stackoverflow.com/testing.html/info so here,i need "info" param 
i am trying this code but isn't working
any solutions?

```
        var url =window.location;
        url = url.split("?")
        url = url[0];
        url = url.split("/");
        page = url[url.length - 1];
        alert(page);
```

Comment: its window.location.href;

Comment: That's not a parameter though, thats the pathname. And why are you splitting on ?, when there are none in your example url?

Comment: @JD `pathname` is better I guess

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `window.location.href`, as `window.location` will return the `Location` object and you need to access the `href` property of `Location` to get the href location of the page.

```js
var url = window.location.href;
url = url.split("?")
url = url[0];
url = url.split("/");
page = url[url.length - 1];
alert(page);
```

Comment: i get only testing.html i need last segment

Comment: @user12858408 what is your URL?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal For a user with your rep, you should have at least looked for a dupe

Comment: i cannnot disclose my url here sorry